# YouTube Analytics: Could not parse content

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api-nodejs-client

I need YouTube Analytics data and I am using [googleapis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis) npm package.

My code looks like this:

```js
// configs
const ids = encodeURIComponent('contentOwner=={contentOwner_id}');
const startDate = '2018-01-01';
const endDate = '2018-01-31';
const metrics = 'views';
const dimensions = 'day';
const filters = encodeURIComponent('channel=={channel_id}');

const youtubeAnalytics = google.youtubeAnalytics('v2');

// call endpoint
youtubeAnalytics.reports
  .query({
    ids,
    'start-date': startDate,
    'end-date': endDate,
    metrics,
    dimensions,
    filters,
    auth,
  })
  .then(results => {
    console.log(results);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error); // error is cought here
  });
```

I get an error:

> ```
> [ { message: 'Could not parse content (contentOwner%3D%3DcontentOwner_id) of field ids.',
> domain: 'global',
> reason: 'badRequest' } ]
> ```

If I do not use encodeURIComponent, I get another error message:

> [ { message: 'Required', domain: 'global', reason: 'required' } ] }

** ------ **UPDATE** ------ **

I changed the version of youtubeAnalytics:

```js
// before: const youtubeAnalytics = google.youtubeAnalytics('v2');
const youtubeAnalytics = google.youtubeAnalytics('v1beta1');
```

That fixed the problem! What do I have to change to be able to use v2?